# Cual es la diferencia entre estas dos formas diferentes de heredar a Tk o Frame?

Tags: python-3.x, poo, tkinter

Porque remarcar self.parent= parent. Si Tk no tiene padre creo yo, además no es más fácil hacerlo de la segunda forma?

class aplicacion1(Tk):

```
def __init__(self,parent):
    Tk.__init__(self,parent)
    self.parent = parent
```

class aplicación2(Frame):

```
def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
    Frame.__init__(self, *args,**kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Principalmente, `tk.Tk()` especifica de manera directa la creación de la ventana o la creación de la raíz inicial, por lo cual cada control o widget se debe especificar en la ventana, sea la raíz o Toplevel, por lo cual cuando usted crea una ventana, la mayoría de veces se usa `Tk` ya que de alguna forma establece la instancia manera directa y global.

Mientras que `tk.Frame` es un marco y solo especifica en el área cliente más que todo la organización de determinados controles o widgets en un grupo, por lo cual usted tiene la capacidad de cambiar el borde o estilo cuando utiliza un marco o `tk.Frame` en la creación de la instancia de clase.

- Heredar `tk.Frame` en la creación de la instancia de clase solo
  agrega un marco global en el área cliente, por lo cual su uso no es
  tan necesario.
- Heredear `tk.Frame` creará una nueva ventana, excepto por el hecho
  de que cualquier control o widget forzará la creación de una ventana
  raíz si aún no la ha creado.
- Heredar `Tk` especificará la creación de la ventana raíz, por lo tanto, `Tk` no requiere de un padre explícitamente, por lo cual, `parent` representa un widget que actúa como padre del objeto actual. Todos los widgets en `Tkinter`, excepto la ventana raíz, requieren un padre.

Comment: Gracias, por la aclaración .